# Django - Get model's children when really the child has its parent's foreign key

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship, django-queryset

I have a small issue, which I know must be easy...however, I can't seem to find the best way to do this, preferably in one query in my view.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ...

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    ...
```

I am able to get the subcategories and categories in **one query** like so, but it's not really what I need:

```
...
subcategories = SubCategory.objects.select_related('category')
subcategories = subcategories.filter(is_active=True)
```

What I really need is the reverse so I get all Categories and their associated Subcategories, but I have no idea how to do that as the Category object does not have a foreign key reference to Subcategory as a many to many...it's set up like that for a reason. (Note: It's set up this way since I have my Subcategories inline on the Category admin so I can add subcategories while on the Category add/edit and can drag and drop the subcategories in my preferred order).

I'd want something like this, just sudo output structure:

```
<Category object>
    <SubCategory object>
    <SubCategory object>
    <SubCategory object>
<Category object>
    <SubCategory object>
    <SubCategory object>
    <SubCategory object>
<Category object>
    <SubCategory object>
    <SubCategory object>
    <SubCategory object>
....
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Become friends with django-mptt https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt It deals with this kind of problems very well. And it is well documented http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you need?

```
category = Category.objects.get(pk=primary_key)
subcategories = category.subcategory_set.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was really after.  Saw your post *AFTER* I figured it out...but thanks so much for the help!

```
categories = Category.objects.prefetch_related('subcategory_set')
categories = categories.filter(is_active=True)
```

This gives me everything I need without querying the database another time for each category.